# rollback not working for multi tenant database

Tags: grails, transactions, multi-tenant, rollback

Im working on grails5.2. I have multi-tenant database setup. Rollback is not working as expected.
Here is my code:

```
@Transactional
def myAction() {

    tableFromMainDb.save(flush: true)
    Tenants.withId(dataSourceName) {
        tableFromTenantDb.save(flush: true)
        anotherTableFromTenantDb.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

If i get exception in "anotherTableFromTenantDb.save(flush: true)", then "tableFromMainDb.save(flush: true)" is rolled back but "tableFromTenantDb.save(flush: true)" is committed.

Comment: It might be helpful to include your Datasource configuration, as well as the two domain objects as well.